# Synonym for "who they say they are?"

Tags: synonyms

Trying to think of a word that means "who they say they are." For instance,

```
The general is actually who he says he is.
```

The closest alternative I can come up with is legitimate. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something the "the very one" fit your situation? See also synonyms in https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/very?s=t

Comment: Yes, this does fit well in my sentence. Thank you!

Comment: How would one use that in the OP's example?

Comment: The general is the very one?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps,
The general is the man he claims to be.